# Validate a Json using the Path Response Schema in an Open API schema where the schema has a $ref (Potentially recursively)

Tags: json, validation, json.net, schema, openapi

Validate a Json using the Path Response Schema in an Open API schema where the schema has a $ref (Potentially recursively)
I'm trying to accomplish something along the lines of:

```
//HttpClient call to the /pet/{petId} endpoint with Get verb here
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
SomeBuiltInSchemaParser.Load(schema.json);
var isValid = SomeBuiltInSchemaParser.IsValid(@"/pet/{petId}", "GET", content);
```

The long of it
I want to test (programmatically in C#) that an endpoint implementing a path returns a json that matches the schema defined in the responses section of the json for that path.
For example, given (heavily redacted, only essential):

```
    {
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Swagger Petstore",
    "termsOfService": "http://swagger.io/terms/",
  },
  "host": "petstore.swagger.io",
  "basePath": "/v2",
  "schemes": [
    "https",
    "http"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/pet/{petId}": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "pet"
        ],
        "summary": "Find pet by ID",
        "description": "Returns a single pet",
        "operationId": "getPetById",
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "petId",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "ID of pet to return",
            "required": true,
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid ID supplied"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Pet not found"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "api_key": []
          }
        ]
      },
    },
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Pet": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name",
        "photoUrls"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int64"
        },
        "category": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Category"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "example": "doggie"
        },
        "photoUrls": {
          "type": "array",
          "xml": {
            "name": "photoUrl",
            "wrapped": true
          },
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "array",
          "xml": {
            "name": "tag",
            "wrapped": true
          },
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Tag"
          }
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "pet status in the store",
          "enum": [
            "available",
            "pending",
            "sold"
          ]
        }
      },
    },
    "ApiResponse": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "code": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int32"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "externalDocs": {
    "description": "Find out more about Swagger",
    "url": "http://swagger.io"
  }
}
```

I have an HttpClient that calls [GET] /pet/{petId} and want to test the json content returned with the 200 status code that it satisfies the schema. Navigating to this path's response schema shows:

```
 "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
```

Instead of being inline, it is a $ref. And could potentially be recursively ref, meaning navigating to #/definitions/Pet, its properties could also be $ref.

Is there a way to implement my above pseudocode with built in .Net or other robust 3rd party such as NewtonSoft? Or do I have to load the json schema and traverse all the $refs with custom code and put them together in the end for each path? I don't mind, but I have a feeling either .Net or Newtonsoft or something else have built-in (well-tested and already optimized) ways of doing this, just couldn't find it.
(Would greatly appreciate if someone already knows for this grinch might steal my Christmas :-))

The following NewtonSoft library calls work on an already concatenated schema

```
// load schema
                JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(jsonSchema);
                JToken data = JToken.Parse(content);

                // validate json
                IList<ValidationError> errors;
                bool valid = data.IsValid(schema, out errors);
```

where content is:

```
{
    "name": "new_field",
    "type": "string",
    "required": false,
}
```

and jsonschema is already put together such as:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "enum": [
        "string",
        "number",
        "boolean",
        "date",
        "address",
        "country",
        "email",
        "jason",
        "url",
        "image",
        "signature",
        "barcode",
        "combined"
      ]
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "static": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "default": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "required": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "optionList": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "combinedFieldNames": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "combinedFieldType": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "combinedFieldSeparator": {
      "type": "string"
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: NewtonSoft's [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) supports `$ref` in schemas.  See e.g. [Create JSON Schema with references](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/CreateJsonSchemaWithReferences.htm).  Have you tested to see whether it works in your case?